# Saving a $_GET method to database change it

Tags: php, mysql, get

good morning, i am Hong Kong people, i hope that my English is ok..

my question is...

i cant save a $_GET method to database, but it has no error. it has a empty record in database..

```
    <form method="get" action="customizeText.php">
            <?php
                $customizeName =  '1set';
                $customizePrice =  $_GET["p"];
                $customizeColor1 = $_GET["c1"];
                $customizeColor2 = $_GET["c2"];
                $customizeColor3 = $_GET["c3"];
                $customizeText1 = 'I';
                $customizeText2 = 'L';
                $customizeText3 = 'U';
                $customizePackage = 'red';
                $quantity = 1;
            ?>

            <div><strong><?php echo $customizeName; ?></strong></div>
            <div class="product-price"><?php echo "$".$customizePrice; ?></div>
            <?php echo $customizeColor1; ?>
            <?php echo $customizeColor2; ?>
            <?php echo $customizeColor3;?>
            <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btnAddAction" name="btnAddAction" /></div>

</form>

<?php     
if (isset($_GET['btnAddAction'])) { 

    $sql= "INSERT INTO customizeproduct (custProName, custProPrice, custProColor1, custProColor2, custProColor3, custProText1, custProText2, custProText3, custProPackage) VALUES ('$customizeName', '$p', '$customizeColor1', '$customizeColor2', '$customizeColor3', '$customizeText1', '$customizeText2', '$customizeText3', '$customizePackage')";
                if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)){
                    echo "SAVE IN DB";
                        }else{
                            echo "NO WAY";  
                        }
```

Also, i try to echo the $customizeColor1, 2, 3 , it can display the data. 
SO, i don't know why i cant save the data in database.

Can someone help me?

Comment: moreover, if i save this sql in database, the custmizeName, Text1, Text2, Text3, Package, and quantity is ok(has value)

Comment: Your form does not seem to have any fields and you are mixing up GET and POST. And sql injection.

Comment: only the Get method variable cant save to database.. why....

Comment: let me try it wait..

Comment: i try to change the form method to get, but it also has empty value..

Comment: See [something about forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form)

Comment: You may want to put `$CustomizePrice`, `$CustomizeColor`, `$CustomizeColor1`, `$CustomizeColor2`, and `$CustomizeColor3` in `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. Use `var_dump();` also to see what's going through or not.

Comment: i try all but it still can't save in db. it save a empty value..

Comment: can anyone help meT_T

Answer (score 0):

You are setting form method as `POST` and accessing form values in `GET`.
Either you need to set form method to `GET` or access form values using `POST`

Comment: Wouldn't [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) help? Or is that discouraged? I'm not a PHP guy, just saw that and got curious.

Comment: You can use `$_REQUEST` as well.

Comment: am i change the variable to  $customizeColor1 = $_REQUEST["c1"]; ??

Comment: @LawrenceChan: 1st question is where is your `c1` textbox or anything in form?

Comment: the c1 is a path variable .. like this

Comment: /customizeText.php?p=499&c1=Green&c2=Red&c3=Blue

Comment: If it's in your URL then it is accessible using `$_REQUEST` as well. Have you tried using `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: yes, i try to change the$_GET["p"]; to $_REQUEST["p"];

Comment: it also can echo the value but it cant save in DB

Comment: can anyone help meT_T

Comment: @LawrenceChan : As on form submit page is refresh and your page url will change, it will not contain parameter p,c1,c2,c3 in url anymore. This is reason variable value is not saving in database. You need to set those values in textbox of form with hidden textfield, then only you can save data in database.